# Displaying a collection of contentful rich text with Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

I am building a Gastby project that uses Contentful to fetch data. In the following example I am trying to display a collection of rich texts.

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import { INLINES, BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"

const LogosGQL = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(query)
  const firstRichContent = data.allContentfulAboutUs.nodes

  return (
    <div>
      {firstRichContent.map((page, index) => {
        renderRichText(page.content, options)
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <b className="font-bold">{text}</b>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [INLINES.HYPERLINK]: (node, children) => {
      const { uri } = node.data
      return (
        <a href={uri} className="underline">
          {children}
        </a>
      )
    },
    [BLOCKS.HEADING_1]: (node, children) => {
      return <h1>{children}</h1>
    },
  },
}

const query = graphql`
  {
    allContentfulAboutUs {
      nodes {
        content {
          raw
        }
        contentful_id
      }
    }
  }
`

export default LogosGQL
```

The error I am seeing is the following:

```
Error in function renderRichText in ./node_modules/gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text.js:14
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'raw')

./node_modules/gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text.js:14
Open in Editor
  12 | // @ts-check
  13 | function renderRichText({
> 14 |   raw,
     |  ^
  15 |   references
  16 | }, options = {}) {
  17 |   const richText = JSON.parse(raw); // If no references are given, there is no need to resolve them
```

I know there is something wrong when I try to map my nodes array because when I tried rendering just a single entry,

```
const LogosGQL = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(query)
  const firstRichContent = data.allContentfulAboutUs.nodes[0].content

  return <div>{renderRichText(firstRichContent, options)}</div>
}
```

I was able to see the output properly rendered on my screen. However, I want the rich text from all my elements. Isn't mapping the nodes array the way to go in this case?

Comment: Is it possible that some of your `content` doesn't have `raw` data? As you said `[0]` works, but does it work for all of the positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the following snippet works:

```
const LogosGQL = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(query)
  const firstRichContent = data.allContentfulAboutUs.nodes[0].content

  return <div>{renderRichText(firstRichContent, options)}</div>
}
```

It seems that some of the `raw` data of `content` node is not properly set in some of the nodes, because the approach is exactly the same.

Try using:

```
 {firstRichContent.map((page, index) => {
    console.log(index);
    renderRichText(page.content, options)
  })}
```

To see the offending position

In addition, because of the way that `useStaticQuery` hook hydrates, it's possible that in use-cases, data comes `null` (or empty), try also using:

```
 {firstRichContent && firstRichContent.map((page, index) => {
    console.log(index);
    renderRichText(page.content, options)
  })}
```

If the snippet above works (meaning that breaks your code in the current scenario) means that the data fetching is not the problem and the issue is in one of the `content` or `raw` positions.

In that case to bypass this nullability you just need to:

```
 {firstRichContent.map((page, index) => {
    if(page.content){
       renderRichText(page.content, options)
    }
  })}
```

Comment: Interestingly, ```console.log``` gives the following result: ```0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4``` meaning that the array is iterated twice. Any idea why that happens? Unfortunately, the last code snippet is not working (I see the same exact error)

Comment: I assume that is because of the use of `useStaticQuery`. depending on your React structure, the `LogosGQL` can be loaded twice on React's lifecycle (i.e: once on the first load and another one when navigating to another page) (check https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/static-vs-normal-queries). The snippet in my answer (`firstRichContent && firstRichContent.map()`) points out that index 5 is the offending one and thanks to the ternary condition we know that the data fetching is properly done. Double-check how's the 5th node set and be sure that is published (use `localhost:8000/___graphql`)

Comment: The implementation of index 5 was indeed the issue. Everything seems to be working just fine now. Thank you for your answers!!